# What are berry grains?

Tags: fruit, food-identification, jam

For several years, I ordered items from Finland. Typically, things not common or not found in the US. To my dismay, the place I ordered from went out of business.

I found another Finnish website that carries many of the same items. I was particularly looking for bilberry jam and I saw that the grocery category I wanted was "Jams, Marmalades, & Berry Grains".

There were several different types of berry grains made from different berries and/or fruits. However, there is no real description. Some may have nutritional info, but nothing else. They are definitely fruit products.

I have never heard of berry grains in the US and I have never seen such a product. I have Google searched several times but all I get are results for wheat berries or other things related to grains, nothing about berries or fruit.

Here's a picture of one of the products, Chokeberry Grain. (Sorry, can't translate.)

[image: Black Chokeberry Grains]

Any idea what this is or what the US equivalent would be?

Comment: What's the Finnish term?

Comment: @Catija Aroniarouhe.

Comment: Ah, I found a better image... Looks like it's a powdered fruit product? Some sort of (possibly freeze-dried) fruit concentrate.

Comment: @Catija Feel free to edit the image in if you like.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The term *rouhe* in Finnish means "something coarsely ground" [[1](http://www.suomienglantisanakirja.fi/rouhe)], [[2](http://www.suomienglantisanakirja.fi/kibble)]. (Google translates it as "groats", but that's a bit too simple.)

Double-checking with the English, German and Italian version of the shop, they always use a version of "grain or granule" in the specific language:  Note that "granello" in Italian, for example, which is about the shape, not a cereal.

As the product sites for the various "rouhe" claim that they use the whole berry, it means whole dried berries (aronia in your case), coarsely ground. The weight and volume data given is "250ml / 85g". I confirmed "dried" (as opposed to compote-style fruit preparations) by weighing a cup of fruit tea: 76 g, but of course a much coarser texture.

---

Edit:

Another [website](http://www.porvoonekokauppa.fi/index.php/verkkokauppa-2/superfoodit/marjajauheet/greenfinns-luomu-aronia-rouhe-detail) writes (according to google translate):

> Berry powders and grits, prepared by grinding whole dried berries, without adding or removing anything.

---

Edit 2:

The [manufacturer](http://www.greenfinns.com/products.html) suggests adding the granules into dairy products or porridge or using them in baked goods.